# Generate Runtime View from Background service Android

Tags: android, service, view, runtime

Can anyone clarify: **Is that any way to create run time view from background services?**

I am creating Runtime Layout Inflater view in activity then creating bitmap of that Inflater view and adding that bitmap in PDF - all is working good in activity.

but I tried this in service but it creating blank PDF - so anyone has implemented before like this, any tactics for this solution - or is there any other way to create dynamic runtime view from background service? 
- everyone will appreciated.

**In Background Service Class**

```
 try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp,null);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear);

        linearLayout.measure(1000, 480);
        linearLayout.layout(100, 0, 1000, 480);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;

        Bitmap pictureBitmap = getBitmapFromView(linearLayout); // obtaining the Bitmap

        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        image.scaleToFit(600f, 740f);

        createPdf();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**For Creating Bitmap From View**

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(LinearLayout view) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();

    if (bgDrawable != null)
    {
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    else
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

**For Creating PDF**

```
private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

    File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/PDFDemo");

    if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
        pdfFolder.mkdir();
        Log.i(TAG, "Pdf Directory created");
    }

    Log.e(TAG,"before document");

    String targetPdf = "/sdcard/TEMP2.pdf";

    File myFile = new File(targetPdf);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,10,10,10,10);

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

    document.open();
    document.setMarginMirroringTopBottom(true);

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        document.add(image);
    }

    document.close();

    Log.e(TAG,"after document");
}
```

Comment: I just threw together a quick test, and it works as expected. Are you sure you're measuring and laying out the inflated `View` before you try to draw it to the PDF?

Comment: @MikeM. i updated my code

Comment: Hmm, dunno. Maybe some glitch in itextpdf. I just used the `PdfDocument` available in the SDK.

Comment: hmm but i have putted pdf creation function in service and its working when i am inflating layout from activity and calling service to generate pdf - will check using PdfDocument yes.

Comment: Well, I know inflating a `View` in a `Service` works just fine, 'cause that's what I just did. Maybe I missing something in your code. Lemme get itextpdf setup here, and see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell ya now, 'cause I copied and pasted your code, and it works for me. I got a valid TEMP2.pdf with nine copies of my layout. Just to make sure, you're looking at the right file, yeah? I'm just asking, because you create a PDFDemo directory, but then TEMP2.pdf gets written to the root directory instead.

Comment: ya i am getting 9 copies but blank - not getting any data that i added in layout.

Comment: Hmm, I really don't know. I tested with just an `ImageView` in a couple `LinearLayout`s. Are you sure the `R.id.linear` `LinearLayout` is the right one? What happens if you set a background color on it?

Comment: ohh - my background and text color was white.

Comment: That's kinda funny, actually, 'cause I just told someone else their problem is that same thing with a `ListView` and its item layout. I shoulda asked you that a while ago. Is it working for you now?

Comment: yup working : ) @MikeM.

Comment: Good to hear. Cheers!